# what is meant by Divide by N and Modulo(N) in counters?

Tags: digital-logic, counter, ripple-counter

I am trying to understand counters. Can anyone of you clarify me about terms (Divide by N) and Modulo(N) used in counter? What exactly it means?

Comment: Do you understand the structure of a digital counter? Do you understand flip-flops? If not, then go do research because any answer that works for you is too big to write here. Of course I'd like to think that your profile gave me some clue about your expertise but, as usual all I see is another mug-shot that means nothing.

Comment: Yes I do understand the structure of a digital counters and I guess Divide by N corresponds to frequency division. Means the output  frequency of counter will be clock frequency/ N. Am I correct?

Comment: Do you have an understanding of modulo maths?

Comment: no I don't know about modulo maths

Comment: modulo(n) = remainder when dividing by n.

Comment: Hey this I know it's an operation of normal mathematics .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Divide by N counter implies that it  divides the input clock frequency by N ie; if you cascade four flip-flops then, the output of every stage is divided by 2, if you are taking the output from the 4th flip-flop, then its output frequency is clock frequency by 16 (2^4).

Example: take a look at the timing diagram of a 3bit counter

[image]

A modulo N counter does the same thing as above and is also used as an alternate definition which implies that the counter counts N states.

Example: If a MOD-10 counter counts 10 states ( 0000 - 1000 )

Answer (score 0):

I think simple answer is this

A counter which is reset at the Nth clock pulse is called Mod N counter or Divide by N counter.

found it [here](http://www.ustudy.in/node/7538)